# Keyboard cover my EditText and musn't use a ScrollView

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

in my View, there a ScrollView on the bottom of the activity. When i want to add text in a EditText, the keyboard cover the EditText and prevent to see what i write. For solve this problem i must use a ScrollView, but i can't because there is a ListView too in my Activity and i can't put a ListView in a ScrollView.

How Solve this problem without ScrollView?

Thanks in advance!

Sorry for the mistakes, i'm french.

Comment: In manifest.xml at the activity tag `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"`